# Windows 10 UWP - How does one show download progress in the taskbar?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, taskbar

When you download something in lets say chrome, you can see the chrome icon in the task bar have a green color go from left to right as the download progresses. How would I be able to accomplish this in a windows UWP app? I tried importing the windows 7 codec pack that I see in tutorials but then UWP won't compile.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo.progressstate

Comment: @Jon That may help but I don't see System.Windows.Shell or PresentationFramework.dll as options to include as references in the uwp project and I don't see it on nuget.

Comment: there was a similar question [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7c317d03-56e3-41ce-aacc-79bcd83f7794/uwp-how-to-use-extended-taskbar-features-like-progressbar-or-thumbnailbuttons?forum=wpdevelop) and the answer is the typical "request a feedback and it might be implemented later". Not sure if they have already implemented it or not.